# Dynamic Checkboxes JQuery Mobile Beta 2

Tags: jquery-mobile

I know with the last build of JQuery Mobile there was a bug when adding dynamic checkboxes and I had to assign them all a unique ID and call the .page() on the element in order for them to render properly

When I upgraded to latest Beta 2 build, this does not seem to work anymore.

I tried a few different things, but can not get the checkboxes to render properly when adding them to the page dynamically.

none of these work right:
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();

and my old bug fix of calling .page() makes it so the checkboxes don't event show up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not yet played around with 1.0b2 however in the blog post about the release the author mentioned a new method of initiating widgets as follows:

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

That comes from the blog post here: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

Here is a jsfiddle of the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cvxDg/

Comment: Yup just figured that out too! Thanks

Comment: The jsfiddle sample doesn't seem to work properly, and it's the same problem I'm facing right now: when you click 'click to add checkbox' in the sample, the second, third, etc. checkbox does not get the jqm css applied but only has the native style. Any idea why only the first checkbox is getting the correct style?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this jsfiddle is that the label "for" attribute isn't matched with the checkbox id, it's hard-coded to `"checkbox-1"`. Change this: `for="checkbox-1"` to this: `"for="checkbox-'+ counter +'"`